# Adding profile fields to registration form asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I am new to mvc and would like to add an additional field to my registration page that is simply a dropdownlist bound to a table in my model (a table of organization names and IDs).  However, in my default application I see that the AccountController is using the RegisterModel model to create the register form view.  This is fine, I don't want to disturb this.  But I want to add a new select box on the page bound to a different model (my model with the organizations).  How do I accomplish this?

I've found other posts that suggest I create a wrapper model for both my model and the RegisterModel, but this isn't working.  My wrapper model looks like this:

```
public class RegisterPeopleModel
    {
        public RegisterModel reg { get; set; }
        public fwfEntities fwf { get; set; }
    }
```

And now the field validator for password is no longer working.  The code in the view:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.reg.ConfirmPassword)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.reg.ConfirmPassword)
    </div>
```

Now renders this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
                <input data-val="true" data-val-equalto="The password and confirmation password do not match." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" id="reg_ConfirmPassword" name="reg.ConfirmPassword" type="password" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="reg.ConfirmPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
```

Notice that the IDs of the span and input no longer match.  The form no longer works at all.  This is leading me to believe I'm taking the wrong approach.  Is there a better way of getting my select list on the page bound to a different model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way of getting my select list on the page bound to a
>   different model?

If the model doesn't meet the requirements of the view you should modify this model. In ASP.NET MVC it is a good practice to design view models and pass only view models to views and not domain models (like for example EF autogenerated classes which is what this `fwfEntities` type seem to be). So design a view model which contains only the properties needed by your view and have your controller action query the database in order to fetch the model then map the model to a view model and finally pass this view model to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing RegisterModel my guess is that ConfirmPassword has not got a required attribute for example;

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A password is required")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

oh I believe the period in the id is replaced with an underscore so as not to cause issues with Jquery.